# localised reviews on the App Store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, review

How can i check that the following code opens the chinese version of the App Store?
Is there a localised version of this code, that will drive the user directly to the correct language version of the review page for my app?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id12345678"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add "it" (italy) or "fr" (france) or else in the url address it should work:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/id12345678
```

Comment: I tried this but during testing using /cn for china, I still get taken to a fully English version of the store.